# How can I improve my social skills?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Some of the items in Star Wars: The Old Republic refer to a "Social Rank", and they won't let me use them until I reach Social Rank 1 (or higher).

What are social points? How do I earn them? Aside from these Social Badges, are there any other benefits from doing so?

Comment: I suggest alcohol. It may not improve your social skills. But once you've had enough, you'll think it does!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're earned from conversations.

Every time you choose a conversation option during a cutscene while in a party, you get Social Points.  In multi-person conversations, each character will roll to see who gets the definitive answer and speaks aloud.

If your character wins the roll and speaks, you get 2 Social Points per person in the conversation (so 8 if you're in a full party).  Everyone who didn't win the roll gets 1 Social Point per participant (4 in a full party).

I'm not sure if the rewards are greater in a Flashpoint, though.

Comment: From my experience, they aren't.

Comment: To clarify @Shadur's answer, he's saying that Flashpoint social points are the same values. Between 2/4 to 4/8 depending on how many other players are in your party.

Answer (score 2):

Social points are earned by completing quests with others as well as doing Flashpoints with groups of people. You get 2-4 per conversation option in a Flashpoint with 2 people, 3-6 with 3 and 4-8 with 4.

They're a way to get people to play with strangers I guess, but most already have a group they know going in so these points are relatively easy to earn, but take a while.

Comment: I thought it was 2-4 in a quest and 4-8 in a flashpoint.  The higher number being what you get if your conversation option is chosen.

Comment: lilserf answer is more on the money. I was going off my experience while questing with a friend. The 1 per person is much more accurate.

Comment: Lame... I play solo. Guess I have to play with someone now...