# What is the bar below the XP bar when I'm in a party?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've noticed that when I'm in a party, a new bar appears below the XP bar.  Hovering over this bar does not explain what it is.

What is this bar, and when does it appear?

Comment: What exactly is the game? We cannot answer without a game title

Comment: It's in the tags. Star Wars: The Old Republic.

Comment: Welcome to the site Drake. All questions on the site are tagged with the game name. In this case, it's [tag:swtor], which is Star Wars: The Old Republic

Comment: Social Rank Bar, perhaps? As per [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42988/how-can-i-improve-my-social-skills)

Comment: @RavenDreamer: While that's a thought, if it were the Social Bar, it'd be about 1/4, as I'm 1/4 the way to Social 2.

Comment: Strange thing, when I looked at the game screen after this question, the bar was there despite me not being in a group.  I was in one earlier, however.

Comment: I don't think it is the social bar. My guess: The Legacy bar. They haven't implemented much of that system yet but say it's coming. Who's with me?!

Comment: I think I need to pay closer attention as to when it appears.  Maybe it's even a bug that happens when I alt-tab out of the game then back, although being farther down the HUD, the bar is shorter than the XP bar (it has curved edges).

Comment: @Mufasa There is also an option somewhere "Show Legacy Bar", which is on by default. So I'm with you.

Comment: @Mufasa: Confirmed. This is the legacy bar. You can toggle the display of the bar via Preferences->Social->Legacy->Show Legacy Bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same bar appeared to me from time to time and I could not figure out when exactly did it show.

After finishing Act 1 and unlocking my Legacy, the bar is displayed all the time and it shows my Legacy Experience.

For now, most of the Legacy features (whatever they are supposed to be) are not implemented, so it's actually useless.