# Is there a way to see your progress to the next level?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there a way to see your character's progress to the next level in SW:TOR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an experience bar along the bottom of your center hotbar.  If you hover over it, it will tell exactly your accumulated and required xp to the next level.  If there is a green range on this meter, that is "rested" xp which builds quickly in rest areas (logged on or off)  or slowly while logged off outside of rest areas.

You may see a bar below the xp bar.  That is the legacy bar.

Comment: thanks a lot!  I was getting nowhere trying to ask in general chat :P

Comment: FYI: The legacy bar can be shown/hidden via the Preferences->Social->Legacy->Show Legacy Bar option. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/43239/1134

Comment: From my experience, "rested" is from staying in rest areas *or* being logged of.